# Should I update the linux firmware if I am not updating the kernel?

Tags: kernel, firmware

I am running Linux Mint 20.3 . Should I update the Linux Firmware that Update Manager is showing if I am not also updating the Kernel update offered? I hesitate to update the 5.4.0-42 Kernel because I am afraid it will replace the driver I am using for my Realtek RTL8125 2.6GbE Network Card (which I had a devil of a time installing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything works fine, there's no need to update the Linux firmware package.

Comment: Thanks!  It works like a charm.  I guess don't fix it if it ain't broke.

Comment: @LinuxMintFan Nice as "thanks" is, this isn't the way to "thank you" in SE sites. The right way is to [accept](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) the helpful answer :-)